# NS2 installation on windows

Tags: windows, ns2

I want to install ns2 on windows, Bloggers suggests cygwin for it but it takes very long time. is there anyother way to install ns2 on windows.

regards,

Answer (score 0):

Actually Cygwin is a only perfect way to install ns2 in windows.. all other ways will not help you.. to minimize the installation time you can skip some additional packages while cygwin installation.

Answer (score 0):

The installation is very fast.
Install first a default configuration for Cygwin.
And gcc-g++ GNU Compiler Collection (C++), make, patch,mingw-w32api,gcc4, gcc4-g++ ,w32api,perl,xorg-servers, xinit,libx11-devel, libXmu-devel

For NS install ns-allinone-2.35

Answer (score 0):

you must have a linux OS, you can try to download Cygwin and use it
in this link you would see the way [here](https://dpprojectdevelopment.wordpress.com/ns2-3-project-support/how-to-install-ns2-on-windows-7-with-the-help-of-cygwin-window/)

Answer (score 0):

```
A better way is to install VMware and then install ubuntu on it. Then you can install very easily ns2 on it. A very good link to install ns2 on ubuntu is:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DiAqKK28Qn0&list=PLIRIdFuHppH5Do4E0SRxWRC6QRCUPwD9l

I am reiterating the steps below  for NS2 after installing VMWare and ubuntu, just in case if the link is not accessible:

Installation of NS2 (ns-2.35) in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Step 1: Install the basic libraries like
$] sudo apt install build-essential autoconf automake libxmu-dev

Step 2: install gcc-4.8 and g++-4.8

open the file using sudo mode
$] sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list

Include the following line
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main universe

$] sudo apt update
$] sudo apt install gcc-4.8 g++-4.8

Step 3: 
Unzip the ns2 packages to home folder

$] tar zxvf ns-allinone-2.35.tar.gz
$] cd ns-allinone-2.35/ns-2.35

Modify the following make files.

~ns-2.35/Makefile.in

Change @CC@ to gcc-4.8
change @CXX@ to g++-4.8

~nam-1.15/Makefile.in
~xgraph-12.2/Makefile.in
~otcl-1.14/Makefile.in

Change in all places 
@CC@ to gcc-4.8
@CPP@ or @CXX@ to g++-4.8

open the file:
~ns-2.35/linkstate/ls.h

Change at the Line no 137 
void eraseAll() { erase(baseMap::begin(), baseMap::end()); }

to This
void eraseAll() { this- erase(baseMap::begin(), baseMap::end()); }

All changes made

Step 4: Open a new terminal

$] cd ns-allinone-2.35/

$] ./install

Step 5 - Set the PATH
Open a new Terminal, 

$] gedit .bashrc 

Paste the following lines

export PATH=$PATH:/home/yourusername/ns-allinone-2.35/bin:/home/yourusername/ns-allinone-2.35/tcl8.5.10/unix:/home/yourusername/ns-allinone-2.35/tk8.5.10/unix

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/yourusername/ns-allinone-2.35/otcl-1.14:/home/yourusername/ns-allinone-2.35/lib
```